# Save torch running model using Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pycharm, word2vec

Currently, I have trained a word2vec model using
[https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-word2vec-in-pytorch-skip-gram-model-e6bae040d2fb.](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-word2vec-in-pytorch-skip-gram-model-e6bae040d2fb)

I am already training the data and I have to save the running model using Pycharm. Is there any way to save the model? If not how can I save this model? Do I have to add class? I have added the code for reference

```
embedding_dims = 5
W1 = Variable(torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float(), requires_grad=True)
W2 = Variable(torch.randn(vocabulary_size, embedding_dims).float(), requires_grad=True)
num_epochs = 100
learning_rate = 0.001

for epo in range(num_epochs):
    loss_val = 0
    for data, target in idx_pairs:
        x = Variable(get_input_layer(data)).float()
        y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([target])).long())

        z1 = torch.matmul(W1, x)
        z2 = torch.matmul(W2, z1)

        log_softmax = F.log_softmax(z2, dim=0)

        loss = F.nll_loss(log_softmax.view(1,-1), y_true)
        loss_val += loss.data
        loss.backward()
        W1.data -= learning_rate * W1.grad.data
        W2.data -= learning_rate * W2.grad.data

        W1.grad.data.zero_()
        W2.grad.data.zero_()
    if epo % 10 == 0:    
        print(f'Loss at epo {epo}: {loss_val/len(idx_pairs)}')
```

Comment: How are you using the model? Right now you have trained weights in `W1` and `W2`.

Comment: @tnwei yes I have trained the weights in W1 and W2